# Specail Character not accepted by DB

Tags: database

I want to add G:tech work in my table columm but my system is giving special characters are not allowed,
We are using SQL server could you please help me who to insert this word in DB and why it is not taking specail characters??

Comment: If you are using MS SQL you should add the `sql-server` tag. If it is another SQL Server please add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support special characters and multiple languages you should use `nvarchar` and `nchar`, at least in MSSQL.